# using request-promise to querystring in JSON

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I have a big API I want to query for userId and receive its details.

```
var options = {
            uri: 'http://www.theapi.net/0862710324bo0',
            method : 'GET',
            useQuerystring: true,
            qs: {
                "must": [
                    { "match": { "data.clients.id": req.params.userId }},
                ]
            },
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
            },
            json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
        };
        console.log(options.qs.must)
    rp(options)
        .then(function (repos) {
            console.log(repos.clients.name);
            res.status(200).json({
                data:repos.clients[0].name
            })
        })...
```

This code returns:

```
[
  {
    match: { 'data.clients.id': 'b2d445-2160-4va7-ref-4edf860bd' }
  }
]
```

undefined (because I didn't specify the object array index)

```
{
    "data": "Sergio"
}
```

What I need:

```
{  
  "id":"ec9c1c4d-ab1a-41b2-bc1a-520b889cdeb9",
   "name":"Sergio",
   "email":"sergio@jorge.com",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding a `"bool"` tag would help you out.

```
var options = {
  uri: 'http://www.theapi.net/0862710324bo0',
  method : 'GET',
  useQuerystring: true,
  qs: {
      "bool": { // Tag added
          "must": [
                  { "match": { "data.clients.id": req.params.userId }},
          ]
      }
  }
  headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
  },
  json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};

console.log(options.qs.must)

rp(options)
  .then(function (repos) {
    console.log(repos.clients.name);
    res.status(200).json({
      data:repos.clients[0].name
    })
  })
```

*Beware - Untested code!*

Comment: The [0] index will not return the correct user Id information from the object

Comment: besides it only searches the first entry of the JSON response, it also won't display any further details such as name and email from the query string. Therefore I can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(repos.clients)) {
    if (req.params.userId === repos.clients[key].id) {
        return res.status(200).json({
            data:repos.clients[key]
        })
    }
}
```